# Regular expression for SSN and phone number

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

The string should not contain SSN or phone number. The regex below does not work, it accepts only xxxxxxxxx format.

Should not contain `xxx-xx-xxxx` or `xxx-xxx-xxx` or `xxxxxxxxx`.

`regex = "^((?!\\d[9]$)|(?!(\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}$)|(?!(\\d{3}-?\\d{3}-?\\d{3})$)$";`

Comment: "does not work" is not helpful; please give specific examples.

Comment: Your regex looks very complicated.  I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for, but from what I can gather, does this work: `^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d-?\d{3}$`

Comment: The string should not contain either xxx-xxx-xxx or xxx-xx-xxxx or xxxxxxxxx (9 digits) numbers. What is the ? for

Comment: This will also knock out US drivers licenses for the states of Colorado, Connecticut, Mississippi, and New Mexico.  Will this be a problem?

Comment: @user679526 What string?  What are you doing with it?

Comment: No, it would not be a problem. I tried the above regular expression, it is still allowing 9 digit number and also xxx-xx-xxxx format numbers.

Comment: Could you show us what you are trying the regex on?

Comment: using in a hibernate valiadtor,  @Pattern(regexp = "^(?!\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d-?\\d{3})$", message = "error")

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in java, but I'm familiar with `?!` being "not followed by".  Your example doesn't have anything before it; I think that's the error.

Comment: @user679526 What exactly you are looking for? Are you looking for all types of `phones number` and `SSN` from given text? Please be specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try:

```
^(?!((\\d{9})|(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})|(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}))$).*
```

To explain, if we read the query you provided:

```
^((?!\\d[9]$)|(?!(\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}$)|(?!(\\d{3}-?\\d{3}-?\\d{3})$)$
```

We could read that:  `is not followed by xxxxxxxxx OR is not followed by xxx-xx-xxxx OR is not followed by xxx-xxx-xxx` (in my version at the top, I rephrased this to be: `is not (xxxxxxxxx OR xxx-xx-xxxx OR xxx-xxx-xxx)`.).

Any string in the world is guaranteed to not match at least two of those, so the combination of them is always true, leaving you with a much simpler effective regex:

```
^$
```

`?!` is a zero-width assertion, so it consumes nothing.  Even when you match what's checked by the lookaheads, you aren't consuming the input, and so you never reach $, that's required outside the lookaheads.  Simply adding a `.*` before the final `$` fixes that.

Your hyphens shouldn't be followed by ?, I don't think.  Making them optional, means you also match `xxx-xxxxxx` and `xxx-xx-x-xxx`.  If that's intended you can add them back, or simplify your regex considerably, to:

```
^(?!\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d-?\\d{3}$).*
```

The other problem is `\\d[9]$` should be `\\d{9}$`

Comment: aa 123-123-124 is not a valid string, but the above regex is allowing it.

Comment: That's right.  If you want to prevent any string being matched containing such a pattern that occurs anywhere within the string, `^(?!.*(\\d{9})|(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})|(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})).*` would do it.

Comment: I  changed the regex to ^(?!.*(\\d{16})|.*(\\d{9})|.*(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})|.*(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})).* to validate "text 123123123" and also "123123123 text"