# Do not allow SSN and phone number in a String REGEX

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for SSN and phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103840/regular-expression-for-ssn-and-phone-number)

```
^(?!.*(\\d{16})|.*(\\d{9})|.*(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})|.*(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3})).*
```

The above `regex` does not allow SSN and phone number in the string. But It is also not allowing `\n` (enter character). If user enters two lines of text by hitting enter this `regex` fails.

Comment: I need an answer, so I reposted the question. What is wrong in it.

Comment: What's wrong is that you're duplicating your "question". The Stack Exchange community heavily frowns upon purposefully duplicated content. Edit your first question to make it a coherent question and it might be re-opened.

Comment: Oh, by the way, deleting your own questions can also trigger a question ban.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the period (`.`) does not match newline characters. If you can't configure `DOTALL` mode, per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222649/any-character-including-newline-java-regex), consider ending with `[\s\S]*` (any number of characters that are or aren't whitespace) rather than `.*`.

Comment: If user enters text new line and then 123-123-123. This content is still validated as correct even though 123-123-123 is an invalid format.

Comment: @user679526 Did you fix every appearance of `.*`, rather than just the final one? Your complicated negative assertion means that you'll have to be very verbose in your replacement. Alternatively, look for a way to say "if you find this regular expression, the string is invalid", which will likely be much simpler and easier to maintain.